# ASP.NET MVC - Making Namespace Available to Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I need to translate strings in my views. Currently, I have a view that looks like this:

```
<div>
  @Org.MyApp.Code.Resources.Strings.Hello
</div>
```

As I have a lot of strings to translate, I wanted to shorten the reference path to:

```
<div>
  @Strings.Hello
</div>
```

In an attempt to do this, I thought I could make a namespace globally visible by adding the following in my `web.config` file.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Org.MyApp.Code.Resources" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which web.config? Should be ~/Views/web.config for razor to pick up on it.

Comment: MyApp, Code, or Resources may be a class, which ,may not be able to be defined as a namespace.

Comment: Did you try @using in the top of the view?